# how do I set the background of cell in datagrid which depend on the data input

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

```xml
<Grid>
   <TextBox x:Name='tb' />
   <DataGrid />
</Grid>
```

I want render the cell's background color in DataGrid whether the cell's value equals to the TextBox.Text which user inputed.
How should I do? someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't reveal much about how the `DataGrid` is used or what kind of data it displays.

If you auto-generate text columns you could for example use a converter to highlight the background, e.g.:

```
public class HighlightConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string text = values[0] as string;
        TextBlock textBlock = values[1] as TextBlock;

        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && textBlock?.Text == text ? Brushes.Yellow : Brushes.White;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox x:Name='tb' />
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding>
                        <MultiBinding.Converter>
                            <local:HighlightConverter />
                        </MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tb" />
                        <Binding Path="Content" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```